# Tomcat 6 is running in Eclipse but localhost:8080 never responds in browser

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat6

I integrated Tomcat 6 into Eclipse Indigo. When I start the server in Eclipse, it shows that Tomcat is up and running, but when I go to localhost:8080 in my browser, it does not respond at all.

I have Tomcat server entry in the Servers tab with "Use Tomcat Installation" and it didnt help me.

I have removed my entire projects from eclipse and started importing it again to set it up from the beginning and it didnt help either.

Could you please some help me out?

Comment: Is tomcat running on port 8080?? Are you sure??

Comment: check your tomcat port whether it is 8080 or something else!

Comment: Are you sure the server is really started on that port? Look if the port is blocked(should say in the console), look if the port is not in use, etc.

Comment: Yes I am sure. Its running on port 8080. It worked fine for me last week. But I have been facing this issue for the last couple of days only.

Comment: I checked it with a netstat. When start the server it shows that port 8080 is listening and when stop the server I dont see port 8080 anymore in netstat....

Comment: Could you be blocking it with a firewall of some kind? Is the JRE running Tomcat allowed to listen for connections? Does the web browser time out or does it say there was no response?

Comment: Thanks for that. I will check the firewall and JRE permissions.... Browser just says "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage"

Answer (score 0):

It is most probable that you are running Tomcat from eclipse as `Use workspace metadata (does not modify Tomcat installation)`. While running under metadata, tomcat's default welcome page is not deployed. So you wont be able to view the welcome page under `localhost:8080/` but you can access your application with the application context in the url ( something like `localhost:8080/yourApplicationContext/hello.jsp`)

See below the image where you can set the server location. If you change it to `Use Tomcat Installation`, eclipse will use the actual installation of tomcat. You can even see this by deploying the application and then open up your file browser, navigate to tomcat directory and you will see your application deployed there in the webapps folder. But if you use `use workspace metadata` option, eclipse makes a stripped copy of your tomcat's installation and places it in the `.metadata` folder of the workspace. Something like `eclipse_workSpace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\`

[image]

The question as to which technique is better totally depends on your use.

Comment: I have already modified the Server location with Use Tomcat Installation and it didnt help either. When I start the server all the Beans associated with my project are loadin in the Console. It means that Tomcat is publishing my project.

Comment: How about the logs ? Are the logs are okay? No errors and exceptions ? Tomcat getting started fine ?

Comment: Yes. No errors in the log. I just get the apr based apache tomcat native library warning. I am trying to remove the server from my eclipse and integrate once more.

Comment: Can you explain how you integrate it in your eclipse ?

Comment: I just add it to the runrimes in the Project Facets.. This time I added to the project Run on Server and I added the server from the location....